# Google Analytics - show pathname in label

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

We're tracking events on our website and we've managed to implement this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'completed', 'pathName/filename');
```

For when a user clicks on a pdf download link. The "pathName/filename" is eg. "whitepapers/mywhitepaper.pdf"

What should I write in the Goal details:

- label equals to ...?
- label starts with ...?
- label regular expression ...?

*In a way, the question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654998/google-analytics-with-jquery-show-pathname-in-label), with the important difference that I've implemented that part with someone's help but I don't know what do to next in the Analytics to reflect that.*

Thanks!

Serge

Comment: This is probably OT (since it's about Configuration, not programming), but what you need depends on your requirements (which we don't know). If you have just one possible value you can use "equals", if all relevant values start with the same string you can use start with, if they have a common pattern (i.e. all values end with ".pdf") you need a regexp. I think this would be better for webmasters.stackexchange,com.

Comment: Thanks for your input Eike. I treated the question as a two-part concept and I thought it would be easier to get an answer here rather than going for the Webmasters section.

Comment: It probably would (most GA folks hang around here and not in Webmasters). I try to stick to SO rules as a matter of principle, but I don't think they always lead to satisfying results.